# MUI styled component + a new prop (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have ListItem and I want you make it red in certain cases. I've created styled mui component:

```
function StyledListItem({ hasErrors, ...props }) {
  const classes = listItemStyles();
  return (
    <ListItem
      classes={{
        root: clsx({
          [classes.root]: hasErrors,
        }),
        selected: clsx({
          [classes.selected]: hasErrors,
        }),
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

In this case I have ESLint error: "'hasErrors' is missing in props validation". If I do this

```
function StyledListItem(props: any) {
...
}
```

I've got Warning: React does not recognize the `hasErrors` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `haserrors` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

How can I get rid of "'hasErrors' is missing in props validation" error?

Comment: Can you put that in a sandbox s owe can see your implementation? Is the first or second your implementation? Since the first removes the hasErrors from props.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-worker-pbze9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark   There is no error on codebox as there is no ESlint but as I said it doesn't like function StyledListItem({ hasErrors, ...props }) it says 'hasErrors' is missing in props validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `[key: string]: React.ReactNode;` into interface solved the problem.

```
interface IStyledListItemProps {
  hasErrors: boolean;
  [key: string]: React.ReactNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ts types to the props like this:

```
function StyledListItem({ hasErrors, ...props }: {hasErrors: boolean}) {
```

This will tell typescript has at least the hasError prop.
This will let you extract it like you do.

You should read more about react + typescript.
If you need children, you can use the React.FC type:

```
function StyledListItem({ hasErrors, ...props }: {hasErrors: boolean, children: JSX.Element}) {
```

Comment: I tried, in this case I'm getting Type '{ children: Element[]; button: true; hasErrors: boolean; selected: boolean; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { hasErrors: boolean; }'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { hasErrors: boolean; }'.

Comment: Also need to mention that that function not a component, just a function in the same file with the main one.

Comment: I updated my asswer, What do you mean its not a component? What are you retunring?

Comment: Getting the same error, it asks for providing all props like button, selected, onClick etc. By saying StyledListItem is not a component I mean that it's just a function. Like here https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-worker-pbze9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark